# Preventing external users from opening Share dialog

Tags: sharepoint-online, external-users

When external users are invited to a SharePoint online site, they are able to click on Share or Shared With and search for other users in the Site Collection. [image]

Is it possible to prevent external users from finding other external users?

I'd like for the external users accessing to be unaware of each other and unable to find out the names of other external users.

While I could certainly use a custom css file to hide the this button it doesn't really solve the problem as internal users should be able to invite external users and share freely. I would just like to prevent external users from even accessing these dialogs.

Edit: After going into the permission group settings, I've made changes so that only members can view other members. In the screenshot above, the Shared with dialog will only show an external users other external users in the same permission group. However, if an external user searches in the Invite people dialog, they can still see other external users.

Edit2: I received an answer from Microsoft Support. Officially, kesava's answer below is correct. There is no OOTB way to prevent users not showing up in search even though the permission groups settings have been set to indicate that we don't want them to. Seems like another case of SharePoint getting 90% of where we want to be. At least there is an answer...

Answer (score 0):

yes that is possible. in general you will add the external user in to a specific group for permissions.

Here you need to change the group permissions so that only group owner can see the owners in the respective groups.

also, i would suggest to create a specific custom permission level for that group where the members can not be able to manage the group and permissions.

Comment: The external users are added to a specific group: [site] Visitors. For each group I have changed the settings so only the group owner can edit the membership of the group and only group members can view members ship. However, external users are still able to see all user accounts. Does this take some time to persist?